# Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined Using FixedColumns in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Using datatables 1.9.4, fixedColumns 3.0.0 with jquery 2.0.3

And when I try to add the FixedColumns I get the error Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined on line 647 of the non minified fixedColumns file:

this.dom.grid.dt.parentNode.insertBefore(nSWrapper, this.dom.grid.dt);

I've tried adding the FixedColumns initialization to the fnInitComplete as some suggested but that doesn't change anything.  I'm using the datatable in a skinned bootstrap site if that makes any difference.  Here is the init code which works perfectly without the fixed columns call:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/SalesDailyReport?' + $.param(params)
        }).done(function (results) {
            var table = $('#chartDiv')
            .empty()
            .append('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable nowrap" id="dailyreport"></table>')
            .find('#dailyreport')
            .dataTable(dtParams);

            new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table);
        })
```

With the chart parameters being passed back from the api are:

```
            bPaginate = false,
            bLengthChange = false,
            bFilter = false,
            bSort = false,
            bInfo = false,
            bAutowidth = true,
            sDom = "",
            sScrollX = "100%",
            sScrollXInner = "150%",
            bScrollCollapse = true,
```

Datatables debugger code: ayupup

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by downgrading a few things:

jQuery 1.8.2
FixedColumns 2.0.3
Datatables 1.9.4

And also overriding a bootstrap style that was causing the fixed column not to work:

```
table{
    max-width: none !important;
}
```